# CUDA Peer-to-Peer Memory Access on RTX2080

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have four RTX2080 GPUs and I want to enable peer access from device 1 to device 0 in following code.

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
float* data; 
cudaMalloc(&data, 1000 * sizeof(float));

cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 0);  // This will fail with error: cudaErrorPeerAccessUnsupported
```

I have checked `unifiedAddressing` of `cudaDeviceProp` and the value is 1. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is the topology of my GPU connection:

```
       GPU0 GPU1 GPU2 GPU3   
GPU0     X  NODE SYS  SYS    
GPU1    NODE X   SYS  SYS    
GPU2    SYS SYS   X   NODE 
GPU3    SYS SYS  NODE  X
```

The Driver Version: 430.40
The CUDA Version: 10.1

Comment: P2P on the RTX2080 is only supported when the nvlink bridge is in place.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think that is a completely valid answer, consider adding it

Answer (score 3):

Turning a comment into an answer:

Peer-to-peer memory access on the RTX2080 is only supported when the [nvlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVLink) bridge hardware is installed between GPUs. That is why you receive an unsupported error in this case.